# Using a custom bindingHandler to update width of elements in Knockout.js

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

I have been trying to create a menu using jQuery and Knockout and I've come up with the following [here](https://jsfiddle.net/danbrownlow/sa1ozzfd/1/).

Ideally, when the user selected a new topic I wanted to calculate the new width of all the elements and then expand the width of the newly selected topic with an animation and the previously selected elements would just change their width.

The way I've managed to do it though means all the elements are updated with their width showing. Is there a nice way where I can only animate the newly selected element and just ignore the others?

Currently I'm using a custom binding handler with the following code:

```
    ko.bindingHandlers.changeWidth = {
  init: function(element, valueAccessor) {
    var value = valueAccessor();
    var width = 960;
    var valueUnwrapped = ko.unwrap(value);

    var newWidth = (960 / valueUnwrapped);
    console.log(newWidth);

    $('.selected').css("width", 0);
    $('.selected').animate({
      width: newWidth
    }, 500);
  }
};
```

Thank you.

Comment: This is heavily dependent on the exact context. Can you share a [mcve], perhaps also your current approach to this issue and why that approach fails / isn't enough?

Comment: Does my jsfiddle not demonstrate the problem well enough? It's minimal and complete (only the parts required to show the problem completely are in the jsfiddle). I guess it's verifiable because I'm described what I wanted to do and what the code I've written actually does. Sorry if I'm missing something.

Comment: It's not entirely clear to me what you're trying to achieve. Something like this? https://jsfiddle.net/ob4gzg0k/

Comment: Hey, yeah! That's more like what I was going for. If you would add it as an answer I'd be happy to mark it as so. Thank you.