# Javascript function explanation - Knockout.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

The other day I asked a question ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38405653/using-a-custom-bindinghandler-to-update-width-of-elements-in-knockout-js)). Someone kindly replied, and their answer does what I orginally intended it to do. However, there's some code I don't understand and I was hoping someone could help me.

```
   self.currentlySelected = ko.computed(function() {
     return self.topics().reduce(function(count, topic) {
      return count + (topic.selected() ? 1 : 0);
     }, 0);
   });
```

Would anyone be kind enough to explain what this function is doing? Thank you!

Comment: I see a lot of functions... Which one are you trying to understand? `.reduce`? `.computed`?

Comment: The reduce function. I think I understand what the .reduce function does, but I don't understand how it works in the context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is using a reduce method on your list of topics, it is traversing each item in your topics observable array, checking to see if it is selected and then adding all of those up. it could look like this too:

```
self.currentlySelected = ko.computed(function() {
  var count = 0
  for(var i = 0; i < self.topics().length; i++){
    var topic = self.topics()[i]
    if(topic.selected()){
      count += 1;
    }
  }
  return count
});
```

the .reduce method is native Javascript method and more can be found [Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

the .computed method is knockout.js and is explained pretty well [Here](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html)

Comment: Ahhh, I see. That's much simpler and I see how the reduce function works now. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

It says that `currentlySelected` is a computed property - to see it's value, you have to evaluate a function.

The function says:

```
1.  Get the topics
2.  Reduce the topics down to a single value, using the following function
3.  If the topic is selected, add 1 to our running total (count).
    Otherwise, add 0.  Our initial value for count is 0.
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's start from the inside out

`self.topics().reduce(/* code... */, 0)` - this is calling [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) on the array stored in `self.topics`. This function works on a collection and reduces it down to a single value - in this case, it's `count + (topic.selected() ? 1 : 0)`, so it returns the count of selected topics. The final part, which is the zero passed last after the counting code `self.topics().reduce(/* code... */, 0)` is the *initial* value of the count. So, it's start from zero, count each selected topic, return the result.

`ko.computed(function() { /* reduction code */ });` is creating a [computed observable](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html) which is an [Knockout observable](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html) that automatically changes if any observables it is relying on change. In this case, this is `self.topics` - any change to those (like adding/removing them) would cause `self.currentlySelected` to be recalculated, so it would always display the...currently selected items. Their count, more specifically.